# Escaping shell command in git alias

Tags: git, shell

I have this command that deletes all local branches that are not in the repo anymore, which I'm trying to add in the .gitconfig:

```
git checkout master && git fetch -p && git branch -l | sed 's/* master//' > /tmp/gitlocal.txt && git branch -r | sed 's/origin\///' > /tmp/gitremote.txt && grep -Fxv -f /tmp/gitremote.txt /tmp/gitlocal.txt | xargs git branch -D
```

I'm trying to put it as an alias, but I'm getting some escaping problems

```
cleanbranches = "!f() { git checkout master && git fetch -p && git branch -l | sed 's/* master//' > /tmp/gitlocal.txt && git branch -r | sed 's/origin\///' > /tmp/gitremote.txt && grep -Fxv -f /tmp/gitremote.txt /tmp/gitlocal.txt | xargs git branch -D; }; f"
```

After some trial and error, I've concluded that

```
sed 's/origin\///'
```

is making the alias break. If I remove this part, the commands are executed (but it's just deleting every branch, instead of keeping the one still on the repo), and have no errors

Any help on how I can escape ?

Extra, but not necessary, if you could explain what that part of the alias is doing and why there are 3 slashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite `sed 's/origin\///'` using different separator, for example, `sed 's|origin/||'` (this command removes substring `origin/` from its input).

So the alias can be set up using:

```
git config --global alias.cleanbranches '!git checkout master && git fetch -p && git branch -l | sed "s/* master//" > /tmp/gitlocal.txt && git branch -r | sed "s|origin/||" > /tmp/gitremote.txt && grep -Fxv -f /tmp/gitremote.txt /tmp/gitlocal.txt | xargs git branch -D'
```

I don't recommend editing `.gitconfig` directly, because it's hard to get the escaping right. I also removed function wrapper (`f() { ...; }; f`), because I don't think it's required.

I would also not recommend using `git branch -D` in such automated way (I did not review the commands inside the alias, so I can't tell whether this is safe).

Comment: Thanks, the alias finally works ! 

As for the command itself, I found it somewhere on the web. It's been working well so far, but I would always copy/paste, which was annoying.

Comment: Great tip about not editing `.gitconfig` directly; I hadn't realised that git would figure out the escaping for you if you use the `git-config` command.